# Can't install cx_Freeze or scipy for Python 3.7 64-bit

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to install cx_Freeze and scipy but I get a

> compile failed with error code 1

error every time. Here's what I see when I try to do it with cx_Freeze:

```
 error: file 'C:\Users\myAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nabp1tpo\cx-fre
eze\cxfreeze-postinstall' does not exist

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\myAccount\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -
c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\myAccount\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
p\\pip-install-nabp1tpo\\cx-freeze\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(
__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __fil
e__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\myAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3
6fbtmht\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed
 with error code 1 in C:\Users\myAccount\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nabp1tpo\c
x-freeze\
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could manage to install it from wheel.

First you need to install wheel:

```
pip install wheel
```

Then go to the following link to download the cx_Freeze wheel file according to you python version and windows version:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze

For 64bit and Python 3.7: cx_Freeze‑5.1.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

On your command prompt change directory to the downloaded folder and use the command:

```
pip install cx_Freeze‑5.1.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

For further description on installing from wheel, check the following link: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels

The same method will solve your problem to install scipy.

Comment: I am getting this error:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64

Comment: cx_Freeze‑5.1.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl is not available anymore on this site.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this problem occurs because the version on PyPI isn't up to date. 
It works for me when I manually download it from the master branch on GitHub.

`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master`

Got this answer from [issue #407](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/407#issuecomment-453035642) published on the GitHub page.

Comment: You can swap out ...@master with ...@5.1.1 for example, to install a specific version (e.g. Tag)

Answer (score 2):

I tried Nischal's solution (which worked) but then ran into more errors down the line.

I then rolled back python to 3.6-32bit and everything worked flawlessly, just a heads up to whoever else gets this, unless you can get cx_freeze 6.0 installed it may be easier to rollback to python3.6 (or make a virtualenv of it).

Comment: cx_Freeze has currently a bug with Python 3.7. Until a corrected version of cx_Freeze is issued, you could also manually patch your local cx_Freeze package as described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/51314105/8516269 instead of rolling back to Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded 32 bit installer when 64 bit didn't work.

```
pip install cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

This works fine for me. So I guess no need to downgrade to Python 3.6

Comment: This is for Python-3.7 (32 bit)

Comment: It seems that it only works on windows, I have an ubuntu 20 is it signals me of the imcopatibility of the platform

Answer (score -1):

I am using Python 3.7 (64-bit)

1. Download [cx_Freeze](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) here (depending on your Python version):
2. And paste this .whl file in working directory.
3. Open command prompt, paste following command and press enter:

```
pip install cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Please note that this command is for **Python 3.7(64-bit)**

4. Output should look like:

> Processing c:\users\Python37\cx_freeze-5.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl*
>
> Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze*
>
> Successfully installed cx-Freeze-5.1.1*

Comment: Which new information which is not already contained in [Nischal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50717003/8516269) does your answer bring?