# How to make a single, cross-platform EXE file in Python 3.7

Tags: executable, python-3.7

I've tried PyInstaller, but it doesn't support Python 3.7. I'm using Python 3.7 features, so I don't want to downgrade to 3.6. How can I make my program a single-file, cross-platform executable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)? For Python 3.7, you need to apply the bugfix described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51692991/8516269) by hand to your local `cx_Freeze` installation until a corrected version has been released.

`cx_Freeze` itself does not support building a single-file executable, but you can use further tools for this purpose as described [here](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by "EXE file".

If you can jam all your source code into a single.py file then that would likely be the closest to a cross platform executable.  It would just require having a python interpreter pre-installed on each OS.

If you are referring to a literal `.exe` executable file that works cross platform; *for python programs this is impossible*.  Python compiles down to machine code in the same way that C and C++ do, which is platform specific.  Unlike Java, which runs on a VM, if you wish to compile your python program into a single executable file, then the file will only work on whatever platform it was compiled on.